# Accessing CSS rules from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Suppose I have the following.

HTML:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo{
   width: 150px;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.width //Equals to "" instead of 150px
$("#foo").css("width") //equals to the expected "150px"
```

or [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r2fr/).
Why can we access the width of the element using jQuery but not using vanilla JS? Is it because external CSS rules are not part of the DOM?

Comment: jQuery uses `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle()` (or the alternatives, when that’s not available). You can use that for properties that don’t have… properties (like in the case of `offset(Width|Height|Left|Top)`).

Comment: jQuery is vanilla JS w/ some pizzaz.  jQuery is pure JavaScript that used to sometimes use Flash to get around some AJAX stuff.  Regardless, if you can do it in jQuery, you can do it w/ *vanilla* JS, you'll just have to manually type it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle). See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r2fr/3/):

```
computedWidth = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("foo"), null).
                getPropertyValue("width");
```

`elem.style` will just give you back inline styles associated with the element, i.e. the contents of the `style=""` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Try [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth). When you try to access `style.width`, it will give you just the width assigned to the element's style property. But in your case it is assigned the width via css rule.

```
document.getElementById("foo").offsetWidth;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNAkP/)**

Edit: [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth) would probably be more appropriate as it gives you the inner width of the element, where as offsetWidth considers borders, margins as well.

Comment: `offsetWidth` will include borders and margins and hence is not equivalent to the CSS `width`. [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth) would be more appropriate, but still does not necessarily reflect the CSS width, always (scrollbars).

Comment: @nmaier Yeah i forgot about clientWidth, just got mixed up in my mind about both. Thanks Updated.